# Resources to describe medieval clothing from different cultures?

Tags: description

I realise this may not be the best place for this question, but I'm not sure where else to ask. I'd like to describe specific clothing from various societies existing when feudalism was still around, and while, for instance, descriptions in ASOIAF are quite helpful, they cover mostly Western European feudal clothing/armour descriptions.
I do not have a particular culture in mind, though I'd love to dabble in East Asian cultures during feudalism. The only one I'm familiar with is Imperial Japan because of classes I've had on the subject, but I'd like a broad array of descriptions from different countries/cultures.

Is there a place/thread/sub-reddit/forum/website/etc I could browse to find helpful descriptions based on cultures and era?

Comment: Do you want modern literary descriptions, contemporary descriptions, or a Wikipedia article would be sufficient?

Comment: @Alexander descriptions that fit in a historical and cultural settings would be good. A wikipedia article would suffice if it was a thorough, solid reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Middle Ages were a period of about 1000 years. Which century are you interested into?
Clothing, armors, societies changed a lot in this age, while still keeping a feudal system.
If you are interested into the later centuries of the Middle Ages you are going to find much more material, including direct depictions from contemporaries.
I suggest you Taleworld's forum, the historical section. While the site is about a video game there are many knowledgeable people in there. Lots of descriptions have been posted.
[The Sage's Guid](https://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?forums/the-sages-guild-historical-discussion.43/)
Check out especially Druzhina's posts for contemporary depictions.
Consider also that in Medieval artwork characters appearance were executed in contemporary clothing. So you can see crucifixion scenes with soldiers in full plate armors and pious ladies in XIII century fashion.

Since they are very popular I will mention also the Osprey's Books. They are often well done but sometimes inaccurate. Beware.